# Testing kernel module using Buildroot external tree but unable to modprobe the module in QEMU

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, kernel-module, buildroot

It's my first time creating a kernel module (device driver) and I just wanted to test out my module in a simulator (QEMU) after I bricked my Raspberry Pi :(

Before I start, my source code is https://github.com/thinkty/n7d-lkm.
(I'm currently following the LDD3 book and I heard that the book is outdated so any advice on the code would also be great!)

I cloned the Buildroot git repository and it's in `~/repos/buildroot`. I didn't want to taint the Buildroot source so I decided to go with a br2-external tree. Based on the documentation and several other StackOverflow posts, I've created the following 3 files in my project directory (`~/projects/n7d-lkm`):

- external.desc

```
name: N7D
desc: Numerical 7 segment display device driver
```

- external.mk

```
################################################################################
#
# n7d
#
################################################################################

N7D_VERSION = 0.1
N7D_SITE = $(BR2_EXTERNAL_N7D_PATH)
N7D_SITE_METHOD = local
N7D_LICNSE = GPL-2.0
N7D_LICENSE_FILES = LICENSE

$(eval $(kernel-module))
$(eval $(generic-package))
```

- Config.in

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_N7D
    bool "n7d"
    depends on BR2_LINUX_KERNEL
    help
        Numerical 7-segment display device driver for linux
        
        https://github.com/thinkty/n7d-lkm.git

comment "n7d needs toolchain w/ headers >= 5.15, and a Linux kernel to be built"
    depends on !BR2_LINUX_KERNEL
```

Is my configuration wrong? [Here](https://gist.github.com/thinkty/42f9f3273f25c4acdfd76d1b99f8c674) is also my `~/repos/buildroot/.config` file.

Also, below are my Makefile and Kbuild:

- Makefile

```
# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

KERNEL_DIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
MODULE_DIR := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(MODULE_DIR) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(MODULE_DIR) clean

.PHONY: default clean
```

- Kbuild

```
MODULE := n7d
OBJECTS := n7d_device.o n7d_main.o

obj-m += $(MODULE).o
$(MODULE)-y := $(OBJECTS)

ccflags-y += -Wall -Werror -Iinclude
```

P.S. It's also my first time writing a StackOverflow question, so please let me know if there is anything missing or something I should do.

I first changed my Buildroot branch to `2023.08.x` (git checkout 2023.08.x).
In my first Buildroot make, I did `make BR2_EXTERNAL=~/projects/n7d-lkm qemu_arm_versatile_defconfig` and did `make BR2_EXTERNAL=~/projects/n7d-lkm menuconfig` to select the `n7d` option under "External options".
Then, I checked in `.config` file in the Buildroot directory and verified that "BR2_PACKAGE_N7D=y" was there.
I tried running a clean rebuild doing `make clean all` but I still couldn't find (tried modprobe, checked modules.dep) my kernel module in QEMU (started QEMU using the script ~/repos/buildroot/output/images/start-qemu.sh).

After seeing a post on StackOverflow with a similar issue [Can't compile a module using buildroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152867/cant-compile-a-module-using-buildroot), I tried to compile the module. Since it compiles fine when I do `make` on the project directory, I tried running `make n7d`, `make N7D`, and `make host-n7d` in buildroot directory to try and build the module itself through Buildroot to the output image but I got an error message `make: *** No rule to make target 'n7d'.  Stop.` so I think my module is not getting recognized by Buildroot at all.

When I just do `make` after changing something in my project, I don't think I'm getting anything related to my project. [Here](https://gist.github.com/thinkty/f412fe6203d0997bfbdc887a308a1136) is the output to the `make` command.
When I do `make | grep n7d`, it returns

```
find: ‘/home/thinkty/repos/buildroot/output/target/usr/libexec/’: No such file or directory
mke2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
```

which I'm not sure why...

I tried updating the Makefile in my project directory to:

```
# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

KERNEL_DIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
MODULE_DIR := $(shell pwd)

MODULE := n7d
OBJECTS := $(addsuffix .o, $(notdir $(basename $(wildcard $(BR2_EXTERNAL_KERNEL_MODULE_PATH)/*.c))))

obj-m += $(MODULE).o
$(MODULE)-y := $(OBJECTS)

ccflags-y += -Wall -Werror -Iinclude

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(MODULE_DIR) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(MODULE_DIR) clean

.PHONY: default clean
```

to see if Kbuild was the issue, but the results were still the same.

Overall, my question is "How do I properly create an external tree of my kernel module to build an image using Buildroot?"

Also, any advice on my code is very appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the Buildroot manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize), the structure for an external tree (simplified) should be:

```
+-- package/
|   +-- package1/
|   |   +-- Config.in
|   |   +-- package1.mk
|   +-- package2/
|       +-- Config.in
|       +-- package2.mk
|
+-- Config.in
+-- external.mk
+-- external.desc
```

I.e., `external.mk` should only contain includes of the `packages` directory.

The package mk file must always be in a directory with the same name as the package.

So, put the contents in `package/n7d/n7d.mk` and put the following in `external.mk`:

```
include $(BR2_EXTERNAL_N7D_PATH)/package/*/*.mk
```